# Copula estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, copula

I want to fit a copula distribution. My question is:

Is it equivalent to estimate the marginal distributions using marginal samples and later estimate the parameters of a copula to estimating all the parameters of the copula and the marginals jointly?

I am thinking of maximum likelihood estimators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these two things are not equivalent. [This post](http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/13576) gives a good example. It seems to be quite common to deal with them separately, though, because this makes it easier to find the copula parameters. But if you want to get the benefit of maximum likelihood, then you need to estimate marginals and copula together. In R, this is implemented in the `copula` package, and probably others too.